# Typescript configuration to use worker_threads

Tags: node.js, multithreading, typescript, web-worker, worker-thread

Im trying to use WebWorkers in Typescript and I have encoutered a problem.
I have installed @types/node and updated everything. 'worker_threads' is not longer experimental and is in stable version of node.js.

This is my typescript config:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "webpack-env",
      "node",
      "dom-mediacapture-record"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

When Im trying to do import in my typescript file like this:

```
import { Worker } from 'worker_threads';
```

Im getting error:

```
This dependency was not found:

* worker_threads in ./src/SpeechRecognizer/SpeechRecognizer.ts

To install it, you can run: npm install --save worker_threads
Type checking and linting in progress...
No type errors found
No lint errors found
Version: typescript 3.6.3, tslint 5.20.0
```

Also Im using Vue.js for frontend.
I have already tried everything I could find so Im glad for every help.
If this wont work I will propably switch to JavaScript.
Thanks.

Comment: You'd use `worker_threads` for worker threads **in Node.js** (that is, server-side). You wouldn't use it **in the browser** (client-side). You'd just use the web-only global `Worker`. Which are you trying to do?

Comment: Im trying to create another thread which will run in my browser. Not server-side. Can you provide some links which will get me on right path of getting it work ?

Comment: Okay, so you don't want/need `worker_threads`, because that's a Node.js thing. You just need to use the global `Worker` (nothing to import). More: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker), [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/).

Comment: Is there a way to write a worker in Typescript ? Does worker file has to be .js ?

Comment: Yes, the worker file has to be JavaScript. So you'd use your compiled output, not your TypeScript source, with `new Worker`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the npm package 'worker-loader'. Goto the below link https://www.npmjs.com/package/worker-loader and refer the section 'Integrating with TypeScript'

Comment: `worker-loader` as of now only works with Web Workers, not `worker_threads`.